# How do I move multiple vertices to the same point at the same time?

Tags: vertices

[image]

As the picture illustrates, I've already starting moving vertices on the Torus to the exact same point (X:0, Y:-49.5, Z:1.5).  The highlighted vertices still need to be moved to that point.  The already moved vertices were moved one at a time (I selected the vertex and then typed in the new coordinates).  I'd love to be able to highlight them all and type in the coordinates and they all move to that point, but it doesn't work that way (It treats them like one object and moves the "center" of that object to the point, which results in interesting but undesired behavior).  Is there a way to accomplish this so I don't have to click and type over and over again, but can simply select all the vertices I want to move and then move them with one simple action?

I've been using Blender since yesterday so I'm new, and the training videos didn't reveal anything helpful.

Comment: If I undertsand that correctly you want to press Alt+M > Collapse with desired vertices selected to merge them at one point (or At Center), then if necessary edit coordinates of new vertex.

Comment: Actually, I JUST figured it out! LOL

Comment: The trick is to go into edit mode, select the vertex that will be the final point for all other vertices, ctrl+S, move cursor to selection.  The select all the vertices you want to move, ctrl+s, move selection to cursor. Bob's your uncle!

Comment: @NicholasAlexanderFilip Could it be you mean shift? By the way, is there a reason you want all edges to meet at the rim instead of the middle?

Comment: If you do as Mr Zak suggests after you do that once then select the next two vertices (in the same order) and press SHIFT +R and it will repeat the last action avoiding the dropdown menu.

Comment: @Dontwalk Shift-R doesn't cease to surprise me. Great find.

Answer (score 2):

The new method, <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>, has already been mentioned. The other solution is to set the pivot point in the header to either active or cursor and then scale the selection to zero <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>RETURN</kbd>. Scaling or rotating around the active element is pretty cool since it makes the last selected, white vertex the center.

It's actually useful to know both ways because with scaling you can exclude an axis. Let's say you want to move them all to the XY position of some topology but leave Z unchanged. Then you can place the cursor on the target and use <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>RETURN</kbd>. There's just the additional step of <kbd>W</kbd><kbd>4</kbd> remove doubles.

Comment: Might want to note that scaling to zero with the set to cursor as in the asker's screenshot will collapse the selected vertices onto the 3D cursor directly, as opposed to just collapsing them onto a median central point as in the other modes

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned above, what I ended up doing was going into edit mode, selecting the vertex that will be the final point for all other vertices, pressed <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and chose Move Cursor to Selection. Then I selected all the vertices I wanted to move, pressed <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, and chose Move Selection to Cursor.